# zapier salesforce trigger for update lead

Tags: salesforce, zapier, zapier-cli

I was trying to create a salesforce integration using zapier. able to trigger action when a new lead is created. I want to know if there is a way to trigger when an existing lead is updated. In [Zapier documentation](https://zapier.com/help/what-salesforce-triggers-and-actions-are-supported/) in the supported triggers update lead is not specified, I would like to know if there is any workaround for this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

David here, from the Zapier Platform team.

There is a workaround! You can find details about it here: https://zapier.com/help/salesforce/#can-i-trigger-from-updated-objects-on-salesforce

The gist is that you set up a `New Outbound Message` trigger, which instructs Salesforce to call out when update events happen.

​Let me know if you've got any other questions!

Comment: I believe you meant to post a different link.

Comment: yeah, I tried that after posting this question but my salesforce trail account doesn't have provision to create workflow rules/outbound messages.